# Pass an array of wchar by reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I want to make a function to allocate memory to an array. Suppose I have this:

```
PWSTR theStrings[] = { L"one", L"two", L"three" };

void foo(PWSTR a, int b) {
    a=new PWSTR[b];
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++) a[i]=L"hello";
    return;
}

int main() {
    foo(theStrings,4);
}
```

My question is, how do you make the function foo and the calling of that function so that after foo is called, theStrings will contain four "hello"

Thanks :)
Reinardus

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Comment: I have to use PWSTR, because that values will then be passed into windows API requiring an array of PWSTR

Comment: Could you use `std::wstring` and unpack the raw arrays with `c_str()` at the appropriate moments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two thing you must do to make this work:

Firstly, you must use a dynamically allocated array, rather than a statically allocated array. In particular, change the line

```
PSWTR theStrings[] = { L"one", L"two", L"three" };
```

into

```
PWSTR * theString = new PWSTR[3];
theString[0] = L"one";
theString[1] = L"two";
theString[2] = L"three";
```

This way, you're dealing with a pointer which can be modified to point to a different region of memory, as opposed to a static array, which utilized a fixed portion of memory.

Secondly, you're function should take either a pointer to a pointer, or a reference to a pointer. The two signatures look like this (respectively):

```
void foo(PWSTR ** a, int b); // pointer to pointer
void foo(PWSTR *& a, int b); // reference to pointer
```

The reference-to-pointer option is nice, since you can pretty much use your old code for `foo`:

```
void foo(PWSTR *& a, int b) {
    a = new PWSTR[b];
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++) a[i]=L"hello";
}
```

And the call to `foo` is still

```
foo(theStrings, 4);
```

So almost nothing must be changed.

With the pointer-to-pointer option, you must always dereference the `a` parameter:

```
void foo(PWST ** a, int b) {
    *a = new PWSTR[b];
    for(int i = 0; i<b; i++) (*a)[i] = L"hello";
}
```

And must call `foo` using the address-of operator:

```
foo(&theStrings, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PWSTR theStrings[] = { L"one", L"two", L"three" };

void foo(PWSTR& a, int b) {
    a=new PWSTR[b];
    for(int i=0;i<b;i++) a[i]=L"hello";
    return;
}

int main() {
    PWSTR pStrings = theStrings;
    foo(pStrings,4);
}
```

But instead of that, consider using `std::vector` and `std::wstring` and so on.

Also, anyway, consider using function result (the `return`) for function results, instead of in/out arguments.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

If you are not required to use PWSTR then you can use [`std::vector`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/)`< std::string >` or [`std::valarray`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/valarray/)`< std::string >`.

If you want to store unicode strings (or wide characters) replace [`std::string`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) with [`std::wstring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3s3k55%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

You can see here on how to convert between CString/LPCTSTR/PWSTR to std::string: [How to convert between various string types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: unfortunately, I have to use PWSTR :(

Comment: but, PWSTR a is a pointer to array of wchar isn't it? What I want to pass is an array of pointer to array of wchar. Well, I will give it a shot though

Answer (score -1):

probably change it to something like

void foo(PWSTR * a, int b)

and

foo(&thestrings, 4);

Comment: nope, it says: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'PWSTR (*)[3]' to 'PWSTR *'

Comment: foo((PWSTR**)&theStrings,4) - sorry no compiler to hand to test for you

Comment: Nope, doesn't work either. Problem is that the array is statically allocated and can not change its size.

Comment: you're right but I was concentrating on the question of passing an array by reference - I assumed pseudo code rather than real.